# Width and height issues

Tags: slider, height, width

Hey im trying to get a title/logo to sit in the right spot and im struggling the height and width of the hole thing is troubling me if you scroll around on the site you can see

http://22twenty.com/Final

css is here:

/*Header or navbar if you prefer ;) */

```
#headerbg{
background: transparent url(img/gradient.png) repeat-x top left; height:504px; width:100%;  margin:0;}

.logo{
    font-size:30px;
    font-family: OpenSans, sans-serif;
    position:absolute;
    text-transform:Uppercase;
    padding-top:90px;
    padding-left:40px;
    }
header{
    z-index:3000;
    width:100%;
}
```

hope someone can help if you need anything else just ask

Thanks

Denver

Comment: Sorry, but I have to ask. :) What exactly do you want to achieve? That the header doesn't scroll and the gradient stays fixed on top of the page? Btw: The first line of your script is throwing a JavaScript error saying that "$" is not defined in Safari.

Comment: hmm ill take a look :S and let me clear my cache

Comment: no it scrolls for me its a padding thing when i remove the padding-left it goes away but its necessary

Comment: You got some corrupt source at: __<div id="headerbg" <div class="logo">__. There is a ">" missing. This is probably not the solution, but try to fix that first. :)

Comment: well that fixed the horizontal would you mind taking a look at probably something i did that make it so it scrolls vertically as id rather it didn't